# Python Error Sending a Request on a Secure Server with Certificate

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate

I am new to Python and working in VS code in windows.
I am trying to send a post request to an API.
I have a .pem file, .key file and using these 2 I have generated a .pfx file with a password. All files are stored in a folder.

I have written a .net application and I can send a request without any problem, which shows certificates are valid. I can also send request via the postman by uploading certificates in the settings section.

I am testing this code on my computer but it will be deployed to Azure once I get it working.

Here is my python code.

```
response = requests.request("POST",url,headers=headers,data=payload,verify=pemFilePath,
timeout=10,
    )
```

Error I get is "(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))

If I try

```
response = requests.request("POST",url,headers=headers,data=payload,cert=(
            "path to .pem",
            "path to .key",
        ),timeout=10,)
```

I get "(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))"

Following code works but I don't want to set false

```
response = requests.request(
    "POST",
    url,
    headers=headers,
    data=payload,
    cert=(pemFilePath, keyFilePath),
    **verify=False,**
    timeout=10,
)
```

**Update 1** - I installed python-certifi-win32 and error went away but when I deployed to Azure function app which is running on Linux I see same error. Is there any way to fix the error?